# Django using generic views, error http 405

Tags: django, http-status-code-405

I am trying use the django generic view for CRUD, but the DeleteView result in error 405, following the guide official Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ , I don't understand where is my error, so that's my code:

## views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    DetailView,
    ListView,
    UpdateView,
    ListView,
    DeleteView
)

from .forms import ContatoModelForm
from .models import Contato
class ContatoCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_create.html'
    form_class = ContatoModelForm
    model = Contato

class ContatoListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_list.html'
    model = Contato

class ContatoDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_detail.html'
    model = Contato

class ContatoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_create.html'
    form_class = ContatoModelForm
    model = Contato

class ContatoDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_delete.html'
    model = Contato
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contato:contato-list')
```

## urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path
 from .views import (
     ContatoCreateView,
     ContatoDeleteView,
     ContatoDetailView,
     ContatoListView,
     ContatoUpdateView,
)
app_name = 'contato'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ContatoListView.as_view(), name='contato-list'),
    path('create/', ContatoCreateView.as_view(), name='contato-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ContatoDetailView.as_view(), name='contato-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', ContatoUpdateView.as_view(), name='contato-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', ContatoDeleteView.as_view(), name='contato-delete'),
]
```

## contato_delete.html

```
<form action='.' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
<dialog class="mdl-dialog">
    <h6>Deseja excluir {{ object.nome }}?</h6>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <input type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--accent" value="Excluir">
        <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</dialog>
</form>
```

## contato_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{ object.nome }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
<a id="show-dialog"  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</a>

{% include "contato/contato_delete.html" %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/dialog.js' %}"></script>

<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">

        <li class="mdl-list__item">
            <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">call</i>
    {{ object.celular }}
  </span>
        </li>

        <li class="mdl-list__item">
            <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">email</i>
    {{ object.email }}
  </span>
        </li>
        <li class="mdl-list__item">
            <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">business</i>
    {{ object.cargo }} na {{ object.empresa}}
  </span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<a href="{% url 'contato:contato-update' object.id %}" id="fab" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--primary">
     <i class="material-icons">create</i>
    </a>

{% endblock %}
```

## contato_list.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block content %}
 <style>
  .demo-list-three {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  #fab {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 900;
  }
</style>

<form method='GET' action=''>
</form>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<ul class="demo-list-three mdl-list">
  <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--three-line">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
        <a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'><span>{{ obj.nome }}</span> 
 </a>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-text-body">
          {{ obj.celular }} <br>
          {{ obj.email }}
         </span>
    </span>

    <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--primary">
  DETALHES
</a>
  </li>
</ul>
 {% endfor %}

 <a href="{% url 'contato:contato-create' %}" id="fab" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--primary">
     <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
    </a>


 {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `405`, Really ? `404` seems more plausible

Comment: Yes, is 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Why do you define `get_object` in every CBV? You just have to define the `model = MyModel`, and let the CBV handle it. That's what is in the docs.

Comment: Then in your CreateView you use this: `queryset = Contato.objects.all()
` Why? You are trying to create a new object, not retrieve a list of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code:

```
class ContatoCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_create.html'
    form_class = ContatoModelForm
    model = Contato # Tell the CBV what object you will create

    #** This doesn't make any sense, you are creating a new Contato not retrieving a queryset.
    # queryset = Contato.objects.all() 

    #** Let the ModelForm handle the validation
    # def form_valid(self, form):
    #    print(form.cleaned_data)
    #    return super().form_valid(form)


 class ContatoListView(ListView):
     template_name = 'contato/contato_list.html'
     model = Contato # This does the work for you

     #** You don't need to do this, unless you want a _specific_ queryset filterd
     # queryset = Contato.objects.all() 



 class ContatoDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_detail.html'
    model = Contato # again, just define the model

    #** let CBV handle this logic
    # def get_object(self):
    #    id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
    #    return get_object_or_404(Contato, id=id_)

class ContatoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_create.html'
    form_class = ContatoModelForm
    model = Contato # again, just define the model

    #** let CBV handle this logic
    # def get_object(self):
    #    id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
    #    return get_object_or_404(Contato, id=id_)

    #** Let the ModelForm handle the validation
    #def form_valid(self, form):
    #    print(form.cleaned_data)
    #    return super().form_valid(form)


class ContatoDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'contato/contato_delete.html'
    model = Contato # the class object you want to delete

    #** let CBV handle this logic
    # def get_object(self):
    #   id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
    #    return get_object_or_404(Contato, id=id_)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contato:contato-list')
```

Comment: So in the class ContatoDetailView how get id ? @guillermochamorro

Comment: okay that's great, understand, i read the docs about CBV, but in my urls.py i changed `<int:id`> to `<int:pk>` than the DetailView is working but when is `<int:id>` the ListView working and Detail don't. @guillermochamorro.

Comment: @PatrickAmaral As ListView retrieves a _list_ of objects you don't call it with a pk, wich is intended for _one_ object.

Comment: I don't understood, because i didn't call the ListView with a pk, i changed the DeitailView url and the ListView stop working. @guillermochamorro

Comment: MMhh it's strange that changing one url makes another not to work. But when you say "stop working" what exactly do you mean? Is there an error, in wich case what is it?

Comment: Yes is the error, when is `<int:id>` return this error `Generic detail view ContatoDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.` in the page detail and when is `<int:pk>` return this `Reverse for 'contato-detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 6}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
` in the main page. @guillermochamorro

Comment: Post the html where of the call to the detail url.

Comment: posted @guillermochamorro

Comment: In base.html there's not a link to detail, it's maybe another template.

Comment: Oh sorry, posted it wrong, posted again, is contato_list.html, @guillermochamorro

Comment: It's not there (`contato-detail`, which is the url that triggeres the error) unless it is `obj.get_absolute_url`, defined I presume in you Model, in which case you are not passing `object.id`.

Comment: yes thanks, ok is working, now we can go back in to the question, error 405 in deleteview. @guillermochamorro

Comment: Did you add `model = Contato` to your DeleteView?

Comment: Yes i did, i will update code of question. @guillermochamorro

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `action` on the form to match the route (url) for deleting a `contato` object.

Basically change the open tag of the `<form>` to:

```
<form action='{{ id }}/delete' method='post'>
```

and pass an `id` to the view through the `context`, like this:

```
class ContatoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Contato
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        context['id'] = self.object.id
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

As an additional recommendation, I'd look into making your routes more RESTful. See this gist for info: https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/09939db6f81d654af06b. Something to note though is that HTML5 forms do not have support for delete (or put) requests. To make a delete request with a form you'd have to submit the request manually on submit using javascript.

Comment: how can i pass the context using generic views in my methods ? @henrywoody

Comment: now is missing QuerySet, you want see my views.py complete? @henrywoody

Comment: @PatrickAmaral have you defined a `model` for the `ContatoDetailView`? If not try adding the line `model = Contato` right under `class ContatoDetailView(DetailView):`

Comment: okay, this return `Generic detail view ContatoDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`. need use this methods out of class? @henrywoody

Comment: @PatrickAmaral try changing `<int:id>` in your route declaration in `urls.py` to `<int:pk>`

Comment: =/ Don't work, no receive id, return this `Invalid block tag on line 1: 'id'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`. @henrywoody

Comment: `{% id %}` for this `{{ id }}`, but the rest don't working.

Comment: @PatrickAmaral did that work? if not what is the error you're getting now?

Comment: yes of course, but have error still, we change the `<int:id>` to `<int:pk>` and return `Reverse for 'contato-detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 6}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']` in my mainpage,  so i tried change in `views.py` in the methods `get_object` than work but in page of detail don't working again with this error `Generic detail view ContatoDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.` @henrywoody

Comment: @PatrickAmaral I think your custom `get_object` methods can be removed so that the default one is used. You'll need to set `model = Contacto` on all those views. Let me know if that changes things regarding the error

Comment: Don't work, maybe is better build the views again without generic views. @henrywoody

Comment: @PatrickAmaral don't give up on CBV, they are very handy and less prone to errors than writing all the functions yourself.